# Can visualforce components from a managed package be used in a visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, visualforce-component

Can we use managed package component inside Visualforce which is developed in org where we installed the package ?

Answer (score 10):

Provided that the component and all required attributes are defined global: yes, you can.

Basically you have to use the right namespace instead of the c in the component tag.

For example if the namespace of your managed package is Foo and the component name is Bar instead of just using this

```
<c:Bar exampleParam="{!exampleValue}"/>
```

prefix it like that

```
<Foo:Bar exampleParam="{!exampleValue}"/>
```

Here you can find some more information:

http://werewolfonsfdc.blogspot.de/2013/06/using-visualforce-components-defined-in.html?m=1